# how to efficiently parse dataframe object into a map of key-value pairs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i'm working with a dataframe with the columns `basketID` and `itemID`. is there a way to efficiently parse through the dataset and generate a map where the keys are `basketID` and the value is a set of all the `itemID` contained within each basket?

my current implementation uses a for loop over the data frame which isn't very scalable. is it possible to do this more efficiently? any help would be appreciated thanks!

[screen shot of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7HNK.png)

the goal is to obtain `basket = Map("b1" -> Set("i1", "i2", "i3"), "b2" -> Set("i2", "i4"), "b3" -> Set("i3", "i5"), "b4" -> Set("i6"))`. heres the implementation I have using a for loop

```
// create empty container
val basket = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Set[String]]()
// loop over all numerical indexes for baskets (b<i>)
for (i <- 1 to 4) {
  basket("b" + i.toString) = Set();
}
// loop over every row in df and store the items to the set
df.collect().foreach(row => 
  basket(row(0).toString) += row(1).toString
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do [aggregateByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/programming-guide.html) operation then collectItAsMap will directly give you the desired result. It is much more efficient than simple groupBy.

```
import scala.collection.mutable
case class Items(basketID: String,itemID: String)
 
 import spark.implicits._
 val result = output.as[Items].rdd.map(x => (x.basketID,x.itemID))
.aggregateByKey[mutable.Buffer[String]](new mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]())
 ((l: mutable.Buffer[String], p: String) => l += p , 
 (l1: mutable.Buffer[String], l2: mutable.Buffer[String]) => (l1 ++ l2).distinct)
.collectAsMap();
```

you can check other aggregation api's like reduceBy and groupBy over [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/programming-guide.html).
please also check [aggregateByKey vs groupByKey vs ReduceByKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364432/spark-difference-between-reducebykey-vs-groupbykey-vs-aggregatebykey-vs-combineb#:%7E:text=groupByKey()%20is%20just%20to,is%20something%20like%20grouping%20%2B%20aggregation.&text=aggregateByKey()%20is%20logically%20same,return%20result%20in%20different%20type.) differences.

Comment: thanks! this was able to work on a small test dataset, but once I run the .collectAsMap() command I get a memory error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". any ideas how I can get around it? my understanding is that there isn't much I can do since the collect function forces everything to go to the driver memory

Comment: check this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574983/how-to-write-spark-dataframe-in-a-single-file-in-local-system-without-using-coal/63577161#63577161 .... you can use ***toLocalIterator*** instead ***collectAsMap***  to tackle memory issues ...  then you need to fill global map by iterating on result of toLocalIterator.... please also check whether any partition size is more than spark.driver.maxResultSize if is the case then increase ***spark.driver.maxResultSize** size as well.

Comment: I increased the driver memory and the original solution ran very fast, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is efficient assuming your dataset is small enough to fit into the driver's memory. `.collect` will give you an array of rows on which you are iterating which is fine. If you want scalability then instead of `Map[String, Set[String]]` (this will reside in driver memory) you can use `PairRDD[String, Set[String]]` (this will be distributed).

```scala
//NOT TESTED

//Assuming df is dataframe with 2 columns, first is your basketId and second is itemId

df.rdd.map(row => (row.getAs[String](0), row.getAs[String](1)).groupByKey().mapValues(x => x.toSet)
```